# can not get output file from aps-run-ilogic.autodesk.io/

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using https://aps-run-ilogic.autodesk.io/ apps to run ilogic rules & getting status as success
but still can not get output file (its empty).

Provided input file, output zip file & ilogic external rule. any suggestion or any mistake I have done.

Comment: I'm afraid there's very little information for the authors of the demo to be able to help. Please consider sharing more details such as the iLogic script and a sample input file. If those are confidential, you can also share them with the team via `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`.